# Point / Vector (Ray) intersect with Point / Vector (Plane) Intersect

Tags: vb.net, vector

I have the following code:

I'm trying to shoot a ray to a plane, and the only information I have is:
Plane - 3 Points (10,0,0), (10,10,0), (20,10,0) and
Ray - 1 Point (10,0,5).

[image: Scheme]

In the image, the information that is known is the green points which is the 3 points. I have the first red point, and the Ray is shot parallel with the Green line. I'm trying to find the second red dot. Which is the intersection of the plane @ the 2nd Green dot.

I'm trying to use the Plane points to get the change in direction to know what the plane's new orientation is.

Any help with the code will be greatly appreciated. It's working in getting the length of the line, but the new coordinate for the Ray where the intersection is doesn't work.

'Vector Math

```
        Dim v1 As Vector3D = New Vector3D(10, 0, 0)
        Dim v2 As Vector3D = New Vector3D(10, 10, 0)

        Dim N1 As Vector3D = v2 - v1
        N1.Normalize()

        Dim v3 As Vector3D = New Vector3D(20,10,0)

        Dim N2 As Vector3D = v2 + v3
        N2.Normalize()

        'New Ray to Intersect with Plane
        Dim vPipe As New Vector3D(10, 0, 5)
        Dim vPipe1 As New Vector3D
        vPipe1 = intersectPlane(N2, v2, vPipe, N1)
        Dim vPipeEnd As New Vector3D
        vPipeEnd = vPipe + vPipe1

        'Create new Shape in Helix
        Dim vPipe3D As ExtrudedVisual3D = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(hlx_Volume))

        With vPipe3D
            .Path.Clear()
            .Path.Add(New Media3D.Point3D(vPipe.X, vPipe.Y, vPipe.Z))
            .Path.Add(New Media3D.Point3D(vPipeEnd.X, vPipeEnd.Y, vPipeEnd.Z))
            .Section.Clear()
            .Section.Add(New Point(0, 0))
            .Section.Add(New Point(0, 50))
            .Section.Add(New Point(50, 50))
            .Section.Add(New Point(50, 0))
        End With
```

And a function to return the intersection of the Point/ Vector (Ray) with a Point /Vector (Plane) .

Function intersectPlane (n As Vector3D, p0 As Vector3D, l0 As Vector3D, l As Vector3D) As Vector3D

```
    Dim t As Single

    'Assuming vectors are all normalized
    Dim denom As Single = Vector3D.DotProduct(n, l)
    If denom > 0.000001 Then
        Dim p010 = p0 - l0
        t = Vector3D.DotProduct(p010, n) / denom
        Return p010
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: A single point is not enough to define a ray. What do you actually want to do? What is the "plane's new orientation"? How does it change?

Comment: I have a single position, and a vector to show direction. Position Vector is (0,10,0). And the normalized direction vector is (1,0,0). http://i.stack.imgur.com/UsKHV.png I'm tring to identify the points in red from the image, I Have the coordinates for all the green points. And the first red ball for the start point.

Comment: Please add a link to this image in the question body and explain what it shows. And especially, what variables you already know (position and orientation of the planes etc.).

Comment: Body updated with the description of the image, and a link to the image.